# How to catch AJAX abort in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which detect any error regarding ajax, I need specifically to get "abort" error for ajax.

How to do it?

```
$(document).bind("ajaxError", function (e, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) { 

});
```

I'm not sure if `if (thrownError == "abort")` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are atmost there see this one

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For your Reference http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/

Hope it may helps :)